# Why `update` and `delete` acquire EXCLUSIVE lock rather than ROW EXCLUSIVE lock in Greenplum?

Tags: deadlock, greenplum

As we known, `insert`,`update` and `delete` commands automatically acquire ROW EXCLUSIVE lock in PostgreSQL. As a fork of PostgreSQL 8.2, why in Greenplum `update` and `delete` commands automatically acquire EXCLUSIVE lock, what's the reason for Greenplum doing so?

Comment: Please look at the this thread to answer your question . https://groups.google.com/a/greenplum.org/forum/#!topic/gpdb-dev/ikoWoVweu40